# proc sql join on clause not working

Tags: sas

Two data sets

One:

```
Date, A
```

Two:

```
StartDate, EndDate, B
```

(All date variables are in a date format)

The below logic is quite clear: join two tables on single key, with date range condition.

```
proc sql;
select a.*, b.*
from One as a left join Two as b
on a.A = b.B
where a.Date between b.StartDate and b.EndDate;
```

But if I move `a.Date between b.StartDate and b.EndDate` to `on` clause, it works without error (not sure it produces the same output).

```
proc sql;
select a.*, b.*
from One as a left join Two as b
on a.A = b.B and a.Date between b.StartDate and b.EndDate;
```

Is this equivalent to original code?

Comment: As stated, the initial query should produce _no_ matches, unelss your datetimes are in a very narrow range (the morning of January 1, 1960).  If the initial query is producing some matches, then you don't have the data you think you do.

Comment: Either way, please include data that gets the error you reference for this to make `question 2` answerable, and split it off into another question.  I will edit this to remove Question 2, and then you can ask that separately with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 queries are different.  The first will initially perform a left join, i.e. preserve the number of rows in dataset One, adding in values from Two where A and B match. The `where` clause will then only keep rows that meet the Date condition, so you could end up with fewer rows than in One.

The second query will only join rows from Two where A and B match and the Date condition is also true.  This time the result should contain the same number of rows as dataset One because there is no `where` clause.

Comment: Note: I edited the question to remove the 'second question', so I'm going to do the same to your answer so it doesn't look confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your WHERE clause.
The reference to a.Date should be DATEPART( a.Date) since a.Date is a DATETIME variable which counts seconds, not days.

Comment: Sorry, I should've removed that also when editing the question to remove the second question.  For the purposes of *this* question, ignore that.